# Elasticsearch bulk insert with NEST returns es_rejected_execution_exception

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert, nest

I am trying to do bulk insert using `.Net API` in `Elasticsearch` and this is the error that I am getting while performing the operation;

```
Error   {Type: es_rejected_execution_exception Reason: "rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$6@604b47a4 on EsThreadPoolExecutor[bulk, queue capacity = 50, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@51f4f734[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 4, queued tasks = 50, completed tasks = 164]]" CausedBy: ""}   Nest.BulkError
```

Is it due to the low space in my system or the bulk insert function itself is not working? My `NEST` version is `5.0` and `Elasticsearch` version is also `5.0`.

Code of the bulk insert logic;

```
public void bulkInsert(List<BaseData> recordList, List<String> listOfIndexName) {
    BulkDescriptor descriptor = new BulkDescriptor();            
    foreach (var j in Enumerable.Range(0, recordList.Count)) {
        descriptor.Index<BaseData>(op => op.Document(recordList[j])
                                           .Index(listOfIndexName[j]));
    }
    var result = clientConnection.Bulk(descriptor);
}
```

Comment: That error means that you're probably sending data faster than your cluster can handle. Try to add a small delay (your mileage may vary) between each bulk call and see if that helps.

Comment: hi Val thanks for the suggestion but could you please elaborate as to where do I add it, because I am calling this bulk function only once !\

Comment: I see 4 active threads which means that your pool of 4 threads is exhausted which in turn means that there are at least 4 calls being handled at the moment you get the error. And 50 other bulk tasks have been queued and are waiting to be processed.

Comment: Ok Val, but is it by any chance a memory issue? because my system doesnt have enough memory for more than 500 mb. And I am trying to insert a document of 6mb max

Comment: I edited your question title to make it easier for others with a similar issue in the future to find the answer  :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Val said in the comments, you're likely sending more data at a time than your cluster can handle. It looks like you might be trying to send **all** your documents in **one** bulk request, which for a lot of documents or large documents may not work.

With `_bulk`, you need to send your data to the cluster in several bulk requests and find the *optimum* number of documents that you can send in each bulk request, in addition to the number of bulk requests that you can send concurrently to your cluster.

There are no hard and fast rules here for the optimum size because it can vary depending on the complexity of your documents, how they are analyzed, the cluster hardware, cluster settings, index settings, etc.

The best thing to do is start with a reasonable number, say 500 documents (or some number that makes sense in your context) in one request, and then go from there. Calculating the total size in bytes of each bulk request is also a good approach to take. If the performance and throughput is insufficient then increase the number of documents, request byte size  or concurrent requests until you start seeing `es_rejected_execution_exception`.

NEST 5.x ships with a handy helper to make bulk requests much easier, using an [`IObservable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx) and the Observable design pattern

```
void Main()
{
    var client = new ElasticClient();

    // can cancel the operation by calling .Cancel() on this
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // set up the bulk all observable
    var bulkAllObservable = client.BulkAll(GetDocuments(), ba => ba
        // number of concurrent requests
        .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(8)
        // in case of 429 response, how long we should wait before retrying
        .BackOffTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        // in case of 429 response, how many times to retry before failing
        .BackOffRetries(2)
        // number of documents to send in each request
        .Size(500)
        .Index("index-name")
        .RefreshOnCompleted(),
        cancellationTokenSource.Token
    );

    var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    Exception ex = null;

    // what to do on each call, when an exception is thrown, and 
    // when the bulk all completes
    var bulkAllObserver = new BulkAllObserver(
        onNext: bulkAllResponse =>
        {
            // do something after each bulk request
        },
        onError: exception =>
        {
            // do something with exception thrown
            ex = exception;
            waitHandle.Set();
        },
        onCompleted: () =>
        {
            // do something when all bulk operations complete
            waitHandle.Set();
        });

    bulkAllObservable.Subscribe(bulkAllObserver);

    // wait for handle to be set.
    waitHandle.WaitOne();

    if (ex != null)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

// Getting documents should be lazily enumerated collection ideally
public static IEnumerable<Document> GetDocuments()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(x =>
        new Document
        {
            Id = x,
            Name = $"Document {x}" 
        }
    );
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Russ :)

Comment: @RussCam for large document collections (millions of docs) is it a good idea to launch BulkAll in a Parallel.ForEach? Otherwise, what is your recommendation to increase performance other than tweaking sizeMbytes, batchSize or these stuff [tune for indexing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html) and  [general recommendations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/general-recommendations.html)?

Comment: @FlorinVîrdol the internals of `BulkAll` run concurrent bulk requests based on `.MaxDegreeOfParallelism(...)` parameter. Thus, running multiple `BulkAll` calls in a concurrent loop like `Parallel.ForEach()` wouldn't have any benefit over a single call and increasing the `.MaxDegreeOfParallelism(...)` parameter, as far as I can see. It would however increase the complexity. For millions of documents, the `IEnumerable<T>` passed to bulk all should enumerate documents from a source and yield them to `BulkAll` i.e. avoid attempting to load the entire collection into memory.