# Elastic Search ingest attachment plugin blocks

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elastic-stack

I am using NEST (C#) and the [ingest attachment plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/ingest-attachment.html) to ingest 10s of thousands of documents into an Elastic search instance. Unfortunately, after a while everything just stands still - i.e. no more documents are ingested. The log shows:

```
[2019-02-20T17:35:07,528][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [BwAAiDl] [gc][7412] overhead, spent [326ms] collecting in the last [1s]
```

Not sure if this tells anyone anything? Btw, are there more efficient ways to ingest many documents (rather than using thousands of REST requests)?

I am using this kind of code:

```
client.Index(new Document
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Path = somePath,
    Content = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(somePath))
}, i => i.Pipeline("attachments"));
```

Define the pipeline:

```
client.PutPipeline("attachments", p => p
    .Description("Document attachment pipeline")
    .Processors(pr => pr
        .Attachment<Document>(a => a
        .Field(f => f.Content)
        .TargetField(f => f.Attachment)
        )
        .Remove<Document>(r => r
        .Field(f => f.Content)
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log indicates that a considerable amount of time is being spent performing Garbage Collection on the Elasticsearch server side; this is very likely to be the cause of large stop events that you are seeing. If you have monitoring enabled on the cluster (ideally exporting such data to a separate cluster), I would look at analysing those to see if it sheds some light on why large GC is happening.

> are there more efficient ways to ingest many documents (rather than using thousands of REST requests)?

Yes, you are indexing each attachment in a separate index request. Depending on the size of each attachment, base64 encoded, you may want to send several in one bulk request

```cs
// Your collection of documents
var documents = new[]
{
    new Document
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Path = "path",
        Content = "content"
    },
    new Document
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Path = "path",
        Content = "content" // base64 encoded bytes
    }
};

var client = new ElasticClient();

var bulkResponse = client.Bulk(b => b
    .Pipeline("attachments")
    .IndexMany(documents)
);
```

If you're reading documents from the filesystem, you probably want to lazily enumerate them and send bulk requests. Here, you can make use of the `BulkAll`  helper method too.

First have some lazily enumerated collection of documents

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Document> GetDocuments()
{
    var count = 0;
    while (count++ < 20)
    {
        yield return new Document
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Path = "path",
            Content = "content" // base64 encoded bytes
        };
    }
}
```

Then configure the `BulkAll` call

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

// set up the observable configuration
var bulkAllObservable = client.BulkAll(GetDocuments(), ba => ba
    .Pipeline("attachments")
    .Size(10)
);

var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

Exception exception = null;

// set up what to do in response to next bulk call, exception and completion
var bulkAllObserver = new BulkAllObserver(
    onNext: response => 
    {
        // perform some action e.g. incrementing counter
        // to indicate how many have been indexed
    },
    onError: e =>
    {
        exception = e;
        waitHandle.Set();
    },
    onCompleted: () =>
    {
        waitHandle.Set();
    });

// start the observable process
bulkAllObservable.Subscribe(bulkAllObserver);

// wait for indexing to finish, either forever,
// or set a max timeout as here.
waitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

if (exception != null)
    throw exception;
```

Size dictates how many documents to send in each request. There are no hard and fast rules for how big this can be for your cluster, because it can depend on a number of factors including ingest pipeline, the mapping of documents, the byte size of documents, the cluster hardware etc. You can configure the observable to retry documents that fail to be indexed, and if you see [`es_rejected_execution_exception`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43468556/1831), you are at the limits of what your cluster can concurrently handle.

Another recommendation is that of document ids. I see you're using new Guids for the ids of documents, which implies to me that you don't care what the value is for each document. If that is the case, I would recommend not sending an Id value, and instead allow Elasticsearch to generate an id for each document. This is very likely to result in an [improvement in performance](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2014/05/choosing-fast-unique-identifier-uuid.html) *(I believe the implementation had changed slightly further in Elasticsearch and Lucene since this post, but the point still stands)*.

Comment: Russ, thanks for this amazing answer! I will try the bulk upload stuff you suggested and try to figure out how to monitor things. TBH this is just a POC running on a smallish VM, maybe that's the reason as well. At the beginning I had out of memory issues, so simply changed the C:\elasticsearch-6.6.0\config\jvm.options file and used these values: -Xms10g -Xmx10g. Maybe that's a stupid choice? Thanks again!

Comment: Btw, how can I let ES create the Id - I could also use the file/path name as UID if that's better than a GUID

Comment: With NEST, if your document has a property with Id on it, then that will be used as the ID of the document. So, simple way to let Elasticsearch generate an id is to not have an Id property on your POCO (or have a value of `null` for Id). **Note:** the id in Elasticsearch is not part of the `_source` document, but part of the hits metadata, with name `_id`, so if Elasticsearch is responsible for generating Ids for documents, and you want these returned on a POCO property, you would need to map this yourself, from the values on the response

Comment: In case someone else reads this in the future. This works great. It ran over night without staling and I use chunks of 10 documents.

Comment: Good to hear @cs0815

Comment: It has just staled again )-: GC message - I will have to investigate ... are there any guidelines on machine specs? I can scale up vertically.